# Adding an integer into a dictionary in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am using Python.

Adding an integer to dictionary value in dictionary adds to all dictionaries in the dictionary.

```
def addQty(req_data, Cat):
    for item in req_data:
        state = item.get("state")
        sub_cat = item.get("sub_category")
        qty = item.get("quantity")
    
        if state in Cat:
            Cat[state][sub_cat] += int(qty)
    print(Cat)
```

The code adds to all dictionaries in the dictionary.

Dictionary `Cat` is created using:

```
def state_and_subcat(State, Subcat):
    Cat = State.copy()
    for state in StateSubCat:
       Cat[state] = Subcat
    return Cat
```

where `State` is built with `{"state": state, "sub_category": subcat, "quantity": qty}`

Using a deepcopy instead of .copy() does not seem to solve the problem.

An example of `Cat` is

> {
> "Alabama": {
> "Accessories": 2976,
> "Appliances": 1729,
> "Art": 3000,
> "Binders": 5974,
> "Bookcases": 868,
> "Chairs": 2356,
> "Copiers": 234,
> "Envelopes": 906,
> "Fasteners": 914,
> "Furnishings": 3563,
> "Labels": 1400,
> "Machines": 440,
> "Paper": 5178,
> "Phones": 3289,
> "Storage": 3158,
> "Supplies": 647,
> "Tables": 1241
> },
> "Arizona": {
> "Accessories": 2976,
> "Appliances": 1729,
> "Art": 3000,
> "Binders": 5974,
> "Bookcases": 868,
> "Chairs": 2356,
> "Copiers": 234,
> "Envelopes": 906,
> "Fasteners": 914,
> "Furnishings": 3563,
> "Labels": 1400,
> "Machines": 440,
> "Paper": 5178,
> "Phones": 3289,
> "Storage": 3158,
> "Supplies": 647,
> "Tables": 1241
> },
> "Arkansas": {
> "Accessories": 2976,
> "Appliances": 1729,
> "Art": 3000,
> "Binders": 5974,
> "Bookcases": 868,
> "Chairs": 2356,
> "Copiers": 234,
> "Envelopes": 906,
> "Fasteners": 914,
> "Furnishings": 3563,
> "Labels": 1400,
> "Machines": 440,
> "Paper": 5178,
> "Phones": 3289,
> "Storage": 3158,
> "Supplies": 647,
> "Tables": 1241
> },
> "California": {
> "Accessories": 2976,
> "Appliances": 1729,
> "Art": 3000,
> "Binders": 5974,
> "Bookcases": 868,
> "Chairs": 2356,
> "Copiers": 234,
> "Envelopes": 906,
> "Fasteners": 914,
> "Furnishings": 3563,
> "Labels": 1400,
> "Machines": 440,
> "Paper": 5178,
> "Phones": 3289,
> "Storage": 3158,
> "Supplies": 647,
> "Tables": 1241
> }

An example of `req_data` is:

> > {
> > "quantity": "7",
> > "state": "Arizona",
> > "sub_category": "Storage"
> > },
> > {
> > "quantity": "2",
> > "state": "California",
> > "sub_category": "Chairs"
> > },
> > {
> > "quantity": "3",
> > "state": "California",
> > "sub_category": "Furnishings"
> > },
> > {
> > "quantity": "5",
> > "state": "Ohio",
> > "sub_category": "Phones"
> > },
> > {
> > "quantity": "2",
> > "state": "Ohio",
> > "sub_category": "Paper"
> > },
> > {
> > "quantity": "9",
> > "state": "Ohio",
> > "sub_category": "Fasteners"
> > },
> > {
> > "quantity": "3",
> > "state": "California",
> > "sub_category": "Paper"
> > },
> > {
> > "quantity": "1",
> > "state": "California",
> > "sub_category": "Paper"
> > },
> > {
> > "quantity": "4",
> > "state": "California",
> > "sub_category": "Art"
> > },
> > {
> > "quantity": "2",
> > "state": "California",
> > "sub_category": "Fasteners"
> > },
> > {
> > "quantity": "3",
> > "state": "California",
> > "sub_category": "Binders"
> > },
> > {
> > "quantity": "6",
> > "state": "California",
> > "sub_category": "Supplies"
> > },
> > {
> > "quantity": "14",
> > "state": "California",
> > "sub_category": "Furnishings"
> > },
> > {
> > "quantity": "2",
> > "state": "Pennsylvania",
> > "sub_category": "Furnishings"
> > },
> > {
> > "quantity": "3",
> > "state": "California",
> > "sub_category": "Art"
> > }

How can I add to the specific `qty` to the `sub_cat` in the `state` only and not to all `state`s?

Comment: It looks like the problem is in the code that generates `Cat`, because your implementation of `addQty` should be fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] if you haven't already. For debugging help, please provide a [mre]. In this case it looks like the problem isn't even in the code you posted, but with how you're creating `Cat`. It looks like all the sub-dicts are the same object, not copies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: List of dictionary stores only last appended value in every iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835197/python-list-of-dictionary-stores-only-last-appended-value-in-every-iteration)

Answer (score 1):

Because every element in `Cat` refers to the same object, the same object gets changed. This should fix it:

```
def state_and_subcat(State, Subcat):
    Cat = State.copy()
    for state in StateSubCat:
       Cat[state] = Subcat.copy()
    return Cat
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you have a dictionary that holds multiple states and each state contains some list of quantities for items (Storage, Chairs etc).

From a list of dictionaries (each with a state, item and a quantity), you want to take the quantity and add it to the master dictionary for that state and item.

Here is a function and list comprehension that together should do what you are trying to do as well.

1. **add_new_quantity()**: This function gets the `k=state`, `i=sub_category`, `j=quantity` from the master, and then returns a new quantity by adding to `j`, if it finds it in the `req_data`. If a new quantity is not found it just returns the original `j`.
2. **List comprehension**: This iterates over the master list returning it in exactly the same form it is in. But, it simply replaces the `quantity` with the above function. The original unaltered master iterator is simply - `{k:{i:j for i,j in v.items()} for k,v in d.items()}`. This will simply return the original master, BUT after iteration through every key value that exists in it. I simply replace the `j` with the above function, which returns a new number if it finds the same state, sub_category in `req_data`, else it returns `j`'s original value.

```
#Assuming this is a list of dictionaries.

req_data = [{'quantity': '7', 'state': 'Arizona', 'sub_category': 'Storage'},
 {'quantity': '2', 'state': 'California', 'sub_category': 'Chairs'},
 {'quantity': '3', 'state': 'California', 'sub_category': 'Furnishings'},
 {'quantity': '5', 'state': 'Ohio', 'sub_category': 'Phones'},
 {'quantity': '2', 'state': 'Ohio', 'sub_category': 'Paper'},
 {'quantity': '9', 'state': 'Ohio', 'sub_category': 'Fasteners'},
 {'quantity': '3', 'state': 'California', 'sub_category': 'Paper'},
 {'quantity': '1', 'state': 'California', 'sub_category': 'Paper'},
 {'quantity': '4', 'state': 'California', 'sub_category': 'Art'},
 {'quantity': '2', 'state': 'California', 'sub_category': 'Fasteners'},
 {'quantity': '3', 'state': 'California', 'sub_category': 'Binders'},
 {'quantity': '6', 'state': 'California', 'sub_category': 'Supplies'},
 {'quantity': '14', 'state': 'California', 'sub_category': 'Furnishings'},
 {'quantity': '2', 'state': 'Pennsylvania', 'sub_category': 'Furnishings'},
 {'quantity': '3', 'state': 'California', 'sub_category': 'Art'}]
```

```
#return original+new quantity if found in req_data
def add_new_quantity(k, i, j, data=req_data):
    new_subs = [r for r in req_data if r['state']==k and r['sub_category']==i]
    try: return j+int(new_subs[0]['quantity'])
    except: return j

#iterate over the master dictionary and update/ignore quantity values
new_master = {k:{i:add_new_quantity(k,i,j) for i,j in v.items()} for k,v in master.items()}
print(new_master)
```

```
#updated master dictionary
{'Alabama': {'Accessories': 2976,
  'Appliances': 1729,
  'Art': 3000,
  'Binders': 5974,
  'Bookcases': 868,
  'Chairs': 2356,
  'Copiers': 234,
  'Envelopes': 906,
  'Fasteners': 914,
  'Furnishings': 3563,
  'Labels': 1400,
  'Machines': 440,
  'Paper': 5178,
  'Phones': 3289,
  'Storage': 3158,
  'Supplies': 647,
  'Tables': 1241},
 'Arizona': {'Accessories': 2976,
  'Appliances': 1729,
  'Art': 3000,
  'Binders': 5974,
  'Bookcases': 868,
  'Chairs': 2356,
  'Copiers': 234,
  'Envelopes': 906,
  'Fasteners': 914,
  'Furnishings': 3563,
  'Labels': 1400,
  'Machines': 440,
  'Paper': 5178,
  'Phones': 3289,
  'Storage': 3165,
  'Supplies': 647,
  'Tables': 1241},
 'Arkansas': {'Accessories': 2976,
  'Appliances': 1729,
  'Art': 3000,
  'Binders': 5974,
  'Bookcases': 868,
  'Chairs': 2356,
  'Copiers': 234,
  'Envelopes': 906,
  'Fasteners': 914,
  'Furnishings': 3563,
  'Labels': 1400,
  'Machines': 440,
  'Paper': 5178,
  'Phones': 3289,
  'Storage': 3158,
  'Supplies': 647,
  'Tables': 1241},
 'California': {'Accessories': 2976,
  'Appliances': 1729,
  'Art': 3004,
  'Binders': 5977,
  'Bookcases': 868,
  'Chairs': 2358,
  'Copiers': 234,
  'Envelopes': 906,
  'Fasteners': 916,
  'Furnishings': 3566,
  'Labels': 1400,
  'Machines': 440,
  'Paper': 5181,
  'Phones': 3289,
  'Storage': 3158,
  'Supplies': 653,
  'Tables': 1241}}
```

PS. I used the variable name `master` instead of `Cat`, feel free to change that as you like.